# Why is the Unity Package Manager unable to download certain packages (with work PC)?

Tags: unity-game-engine, self-signed-certificate

I have used Unity at home (personal hobby) for years with no issues, however I was recently asked to do something at work that required Unity, so I installed it on my work laptop. (I work for a large tech company, however I work from home and do not need to VPN in for work). I first tried to create a "3D (URP)" project, however the project itself failed to be created, as it failed to download certain files, giving me errors similar to what is seen below.

After that, I tried to create a "standard" 3D project, and that worked! At least I could get into the editor now, so I tried to go to the Package manager and add the Universal RP package by hand. I also tried to update the test-framework package. Below are the results:

```
[Package Manager Window] Cannot perform upm operation: Unable to add package [com.unity.render-pipelines.universal@12.1.10]:
  One or more dependencies could not be added to the local file system:
    com.unity.burst: self signed certificate in certificate chain [NotFound].
UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallUpdateFunctions ()

[Package Manager Window] Error adding package: com.unity.render-pipelines.universal@12.1.10.
UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallUpdateFunctions ()

[Package Manager Window] Cannot perform upm operation: self signed certificate in certificate chain [NotFound].
UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallUpdateFunctions ()

[Package Manager Window] Error adding package: com.unity.test-framework@1.1.33.
UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallUpdateFunctions ()
```

Has anyone run into this problem? I haven't seen much at all about it on the web, although I did see a mention of someone's workplace somehow not allowing self-signed certificates or something like that? Does that ring a bell for anyone?

I'm trying to figure out "What" it is, so that if it turns out to be environmental somehow, I can least point them to a given solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you ask your IT?  The security software they use might be logging the reasons for blocking the packages,  They might also be willing to allow-list the packages.